# Copied text is returned as boolean

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with two sheets. One is the "All Current Projects" aka ACP  and the other is "Create Appointments" aka CA. I want to copy certain data from ACP and place it into CA.

I filter the data to pull based on Column L which has dates. I only want to pull data from dates that are in the future. Once I find the row, I offset from the cell in column L to copy data in the same row.

The offset cells contents are on the clipboard just fine, but when the data is placed in CA, it comes back as "True" although I have it dimmed as a string.

```
Sub CopyApptDetails()

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("All Current Projects").Select

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Subject As String


'Search Range for cells to exclude empty cells
For Each Cell In Range("L4:L80")
If Cell.Value <> 0 Then
    If Cell.Value >= Now() Then

        Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cell.Value + 14 'Start Date
        Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "10:00:00 AM" ' Start Time

        Subject = Cell.Offset(0, -2).Copy
        Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Subject ' Subject Line


    End If
End If
Next Cell

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Create Appointments").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I see you copy something, however you never paste it.

Comment: `Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cell.Offset(0, -2).Value` perhaps this works instead of using the subject variable.

Comment: Change the `.Copy` to a `.Value`

Comment: Both of those solutions worked. Thank you guys!